# Populate Webpage field with Excel VBA MSXML2.XMLHTTP

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping

I am very new to VBA programming and spending lots of time learning this. Recently, I am trying to learn MSXML2.XMLHTTP- how to get data from a webpage and how to input data from excel into the webpage field.

To do so, I am trying to Create a new Facebook account using XML and not IE or an HTTP request with Excel VBA. I consider opening Facebook account, because here I can learn how to handle all types of control (text field, dropdown, Radio button, submit button)

Values will be taken from an excel sheet and populate the webpage:-
https://web.facebook.com/

• First name is in Cell ("A1")

• Last name is in Cell ("A2")

• Mail ID is in Cell ("A3")

• Password is in Cell ("A4")

• Date of Birth is in Cell ("A5"). A big challenge to select values from the dropdown.

• Gender is in Cell ("A6")

• need to click the button "Sign up"

Really appreciate your help to enrich my coding knowledge.

[image]

Comment: If its purely a learning exercise I'd probably start with a different target. I would expect FB to have captchas and other things specifically designed to hinder automation.

Comment: You can't really do this type of thing using XMHTTP - you need to use browser automation.

Comment: @TimWilliams, do you mean, with XMHTTP, Only I can extract web page data, but I cannot post data into a webpage from excel? 
Even I cannot update click any button?

Comment: xmlhttp is not an "interactive" environment

Comment: xmlhttp is like an API, if facebook doesn't provide a way to create an account through an automated interface (what is not the case for obvious resasons) you can't automate things like this with VBA. VBA is only a scripting langauge to automate things in office application. So you would have problems to get the object for the browser anyways to use it.

Comment: Yeah i got it. Thanks you so much